# Untargetting .Net framework within a Xamarin project

Tags: .net, xamarin, arcgis, esri

When trying to install the ArcGis Runtime for Xamarin nuget package which is only compatible with UWP, iOS and Android I get the following error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     Could not install package 'Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Xamarin.Forms
>   100.0.0.1369-beta'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.6,Profile=Profile44',
>   but the package does not contain any assembly references or content
>   files that are compatible with that framework. For more information,
>   contact the package author.           0

This is normal as my Xamarin library is targetting the .Net Framework. But when I try to untarget the .Net framework I receive the following message:

> The following will be automatically targeted because they support the same set of portable APIs: .Net Framework 4.5.1; Windows 8.1; Xamarion.iOS (Classic).

How am I able to create a cross platform library with the NuGet package installed when the common denominator (.Net 4.5.1 as far as I am understanding) doesn't work?

Edit:

The link for the NuGet package as requested:

[https://earlyadopter.esri.com/project/version/item.html?cap=4DBE143A73CC4E629BA34DDE5090139C&arttypeid={8FA6BFFA-5375-4535-8663-F281D7BAC1FA}&artid={04EA6FA2-E552-4357-BDFE-1177D193DD2B}](https://earlyadopter.esri.com/project/version/item.html?cap=4DBE143A73CC4E629BA34DDE5090139C&arttypeid=%7B8FA6BFFA-5375-4535-8663-F281D7BAC1FA%7D&artid=%7B04EA6FA2-E552-4357-BDFE-1177D193DD2B%7D)

It is the Xamarin.Forms NuGet package I'm trying to install.

You have to be signed in order to be able to view the package. Creating an account is free and doesn't require you to be part of an enterprise which has a deal with Esri though.

Comment: Can you add a link to the nuget package here? Ideally it's saying you are using a PCL profile that does not contain any assembly references that are compatible. Thus you would need to be under a PCL profile that it can be installed into (The .nupkg might have more information here)

Comment: You might manually open your project file in notepad and edit its profile to 44.

Comment: @JonDouglas The link: https://earlyadopter.esri.com/project/version/item.html?cap=4DBE143A73CC4E629BA34DDE5090139C&arttypeid=%7B8FA6BFFA-5375-4535-8663-F281D7BAC1FA%7D&artid=%7B04EA6FA2-E552-4357-BDFE-1177D193DD2B%7D

Comment: @LexLi : Will give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: @LexLi Just got time to try out your solution, but it's already on profile 44. I found a couple of profiles ( http://embed.plnkr.co/03ck2dCtnJogBKHJ9EjY ) but which one do I have to use?

Comment: Please try their sample project first, https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-runtime-samples-xamarin After initial compilation and package restore, you can go to "packages" folder to analyze what are the profiles supported by this package. You can then revise your project file accordingly. Note that the official sample projects use a Xamarin.Forms Shared project, which is more suitable than a PCL project.